# How to get a percentage from an array value

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get a percentage from an array value in a for-loop.

```
  System.out.println(playerName[i+1] + " got " + playerScore[i] + " questions right out of " + question.length + "!\n");
  double playerScorePercentage = (playerScore[i] / question.length) * 100;
  System.out.println("Which is " + playerScorePercentage + "%!");
```

What am I doing wrong? The `playerScore`displays a value but when I am trying to do a calculation with it below, it displays 0.0 no matter what.

An example run:

```
John got 3 questions right out of 10!
Which is 0.0%!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the values before the division:

```
double playerScorePercentage = ((double)playerScore[i] / (double)question.length) * 100;
```

And search the web for "integer division" if you don't know the topic.